# Volume of a solid bounded by surfaces - is it correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Could you check if my calculations and reasoning are correct.

And maybe suggest a nicer way of solving this problem?

We are given a solid bounded by these surfaces:

$y=x^2, \ y=1, \ 2x+y+z = 4, \ z=0$

I drew a picture, and it appears that

$z$ goes from $0$ up to $4-2x-y$ (the region below $z=0$  isn't bounded, here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2By%2Bz%3D4 )

$y$ goes from $0$ to $1$  (due to $y = x^2$)

and $x$ goes from $-\sqrt{y}$ to $\sqrt{y}$

Now is it correct to use thses limits to integrate $\int \int \int dz dx dy$?

I would really appreciate all your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks pretty much correct. But you *don't* want to integrate in that order: you need your outermost integral to not depend on the values of inner variables. So a good choice is
$$
\int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^\sqrt{y}\int_0^{4-2x-y} \ldots ~dz     ~dx~dy
$$

Now the value of the upper limit on $z$ is well-defined at the point it's used, etc. If this doesn't make sense, just ask and I'll try to say more.

Comment: You wrote dz dy dy. Where should dx be? In the end? dz dy dx?

Comment: Fixed: the middle dy should have been a dx. Fingers faster than brain. :(

Comment: I see :) Thanks a lot! One more thing, though. Why are there dots in the integral?

Comment: Those stand for the thing you're integrating. Now that I look at the title and see that it's the VOLUME that you want, I can tell you that the dots stand for "the number 1". :)

Comment: I thought so, but I wanted to make sure. Thanks again :)